# `get_loaded_extensions()` shows nothing in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework

I use the below code for showing my php modules:

In `index.php`:

```
<?php get_loaded_extensions();
```

but when I tried to access `index.php` this shows nothing in the browser.

I use the command `php -m`, there can shows many modules:

```
[root@localhost html]# php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
filter
...

[Zend Modules]
```

Comment: RTM, it returns an array, you still need to output the results...

Comment: print_r(get_loaded_extensions());

Comment: If you are searching for inconsistencies the next time: your shell version (`php -m`) and your webserver version of PHP might use different configurations. They do not need to share the same `php.ini`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function returns an array.

```
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
```

Answer (score 0):

OK the problem is that you are just calling get_loaded_extensions() without doing anything with the return value.

Per http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php  get_loaded_extensions() returns an array with the names of all modules compiled and loaded.

So try this instead and it should work:

```
<?php
  $extensions_array = get_loaded_extensions();
  var_dump($extensions_array);
```